# Bash Expect script, send command

Tags: bash, expect

I have the following script working. I would like the result of command `send -- "/system identity print\r"` executed saved to a file, but it is probably badly written. At the moment, I can only write the path to the file tmp.

```
#!/bin/bash
HOSTNAME="xx.xx.xx.xx"
PORT="22422"
USER="admin"
PASS="pass"
TMP=$(mktemp)
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin"

# Create Expect script
cat > $TMP << EOF
#exp_internal 1 # Uncomment for debug
set timeout -1
spawn ssh -p$PORT $USER@$HOSTNAME
match_max 100000
expect -exact "password:"
send -- "$PASS\r"
expect " > "
$nazwa send -- "/system identity print\r"
expect " > "
send -- "quit\r"
expect eof
EOF

# Run Expect script
#cat $TMP # Uncomment for debug
expect -f $TMP
echo $TMP >> log.log
# remove expect script
rm $TMP
```

Comment: Don't use `expect` to connect `ssh`! Store your public key to `authorized_keys` at dest host instead!

Comment: What's `$nazva`.. What's this line `system..print` ??? What's the goal? Where do you want to go, today??

Comment: @Michal_B: If you don't answer to my last question. Ideally by editing your question, they will be closed in a few moment!!

Answer (score -1):

Since your are actually developing your script, uncomment `exp_internal 1` to get Expect to help you.